# inserting record from one table to another using record in postgres for loop

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, record

I'm trying to insert data from one table to another in postgres using for...loop. The approach is given below.

```
DO LANGUAGE PLPGSQL $$
DECLARE
data record;

BEGIN

FOR data IN SELECT * FROM forall_data
LOOP
INSERT INTO for_loop values data;<br>
END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

I've used record for the row iteration but couldn't find out how to insert that 'data' into 'for_loop' table. When I run this code it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "data"
LINE 9: INSERT INTO for_loop values data;
                                    ^
```

Here are my two tables.

```
create table forall_data(
nid numeric(15,0)not null,
name varchar(15) not null,
city varchar(10) not null,
contact numeric(11,0) not null
);

create table for_loop(
nid numeric(15,0)not null,
name varchar(15) not null,
city varchar(10) not null,
contact numeric(11,0) not null
);
```

What should I try here to insert that 'data' record into 'for_loop' table? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want a loop if it could be done without a loop?

Comment: @wildplasser I know. But I'm working on oracle to postgres migration project where bulk collect... forall is an issue to deal with in this manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code:

```
DO LANGUAGE PLPGSQL $$
DECLARE
rec record;

BEGIN

FOR rec IN SELECT * FROM budzet.forall_data
LOOP
INSERT INTO budzet.for_loop(nid, name , city , contact)
    VALUES (rec.nid, rec.name , rec.city , rec.contact);

END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO for_loop values (data.nid,data.name,data.city,    data.contact); `
this ones works, but is there any way that I don't have to use these column names for the record??

Comment: Apparently for my approach using record your answer is correct, need to mention the column names for the untyped record. But I've tried using `%rowtype` or table type which solve the column names issue

Answer (score 5):

'data' is untyped record, so I have to mention the column name to retrieve the value of this record.

```
DO LANGUAGE PLPGSQL $$
DECLARE
data record;

BEGIN

FOR data IN SELECT * FROM forall_data
LOOP
INSERT INTO for_loop values (data.nid,data.name,data.city,data.contact);
END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

But using %rowtype or table type is more flexible and no need to mention the column names to retrieve column value from the variable

```
DO LANGUAGE PLPGSQL $$
DECLARE
data forall_data;  --- or data forall_data%rowtype 

BEGIN

FOR data IN SELECT * FROM forall_data
LOOP
INSERT INTO for_loop select (data).*;
END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Loop with some exit condition.

```
    DO LANGUAGE PLPGSQL $$
    DECLARE
    rec CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM forall_data;
    V_nid numeric;
    V_name varchar(15);
    V_city varchar(10);
    V_contact numeric;

    BEGIN
    OPEN rec;
    LOOP
    FETCH rec INTO V_nid ,V_name ,V_city,V_contact;
     EXIT WHEN(rec IS NULL);
    INSERT INTO for_loop(nid, name , city , contact)
        VALUES (V_nid , V_name , V_city , V_contact);

    END LOOP;
CLOSE rec;
    END;
    $$
```

Hope it work for you.

> EDIT: Alternately you can try this without using loop insert statement from one table and select statement from another table.

```
INSERT INTO for_loop(nid, name , city , contact)
select nid, name , city , contact FROM forall_data;
```

Comment: this is an example for a shorter table. If I have many number of columns then I have to initialize a variable for each of these columns? I need more dynamic, not initializing newer variables in code but from record.